# Arguement 1 must be instance of Illuminate\Http\Request integer given

Tags: php, laravel, controller, request

When I am trying to send mail, everytime a new member is added to the user table, so that they can get a setup password link. I have been trying to get this to work but seem not to be.

```
 public function store(AddUser $request)
{
    $user = $request->all();
    $user['activate'] = $this->active();
    $user['guid'] = $this->guid();
    $user['accountno'] = $this->generateAndValidateAccountno();



  $check = User::find($user['phone']);

    if(!$check) {

        $id = User::create($user);

        $this->sendEmail($user['accountno']);
    }
    return redirect('employee');
}


 public function sendEmail(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    Beautymail::send('emails.welcome', [], function($message)
{
    $message
        ->to('$id->email', '$id->fname')
        ->subject('Welcome!');
    });
}
}
```

Not sure what am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same request class in the controller and the model. In your user model, add `use Illuminate\Http\Request` at the top of the class to tell it which Request class to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

`public function sendEmail(Request $request, $id){...}`

to

`public function sendEmail($id){...}`